# How to handle this type of JSON request in akka http POST endpoint?

Tags: json, scala, http-post, akka, akka-http

I have a scala application which contains an akka http server with a POST endpoint. Currently I am sending below 3 fields in the json request:

```
{
  "f1": "string1",
  "f2": "string2",
  "f3": "string3"
}
```

The code for *ModelRequest* object look like this:

```
import akka.http.scaladsl.marshallers.sprayjson.SprayJsonSupport
import spray.json.DefaultJsonProtocol

case class ModelRequest(f1: String, f2: String, f3: String)
object ModelJsonSupport extends DefaultJsonProtocol with SprayJsonSupport {
  implicit val PortofolioFormats = jsonFormat3(ModelRequest)
}
```

and this is how we are using this *ModelRequest* in our route:

```
val route = path("infer") {
      post {
        entity(as[ModelRequest]) { modelRequest =>
          complete(myFunc(modelRequest.f1, modelRequest.f2))
        }
      }
    }
```

Now, I want to send a variable number of fields instead of above 3 to our endpoint with any data type. How can I do that? And I want to extract only one field whose name I know from this JSON input. For example, now my request can look something like this:

```
{
    "f1":33,
    "g1": 44,
    "random_feat": "hello"
    ......
    ......
    "imp":{"feat1":"hi","feat2":4543}
}
```

From this request JSON, I only want to extract *"imp"* out of it and for the rest of the fields, I don't care. This request can have 2, 5 or 20 fields but I know that this will definitely have this "imp" field which I want to use in my application. How to do that? Moreover this complete request JSON will be forwarded to some other POST endpoint internally in my application which is also I am not sure how to do. Please help if you have any leads. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

spray ignores additional fields by default, it should work

```
final case class Request(imp: Imp)
final case class Imp(feat1: String, feat2: Long)

object Imp extends SprayJsonSupport with DefaultJsonProtocol {

  implicit val formatter = jsonFormat2(Imp.apply)
}

object Request extends SprayJsonSupport with DefaultJsonProtocol {

  implicit val formatter = jsonFormat1(Request.apply)
}
```